# Nginx listening to port 80 in AWS Fargate

Tags: aws-fargate

I want to host a nginx listening to port 80 in Fargate, and serve a website behind.

Does that mean the Fargate will run in 7/24?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it does mean that. You will be paying for 100% uptime

Comment: Yes. Fargate task will need to run continuously, 24/7

Comment: @apokryfos Yogi, thanks for the prompt reply. Then, I think that is very expensive in cost. But I don't want to maintain EC2, so, I think I will still go for Fargate. Thank you

Comment: What we use often is hosting a website on S3 behind CloudFront and putting an API in AWS Lambda. It gets tricky to implement on Lambda though because there are quirks to be aware of

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use nginx? If you just need to serve a static website, then you could try something like Amplify hosting or even just S3.

Comment: @RicardoSueiras Actually, my use case is 1. hosting a `next-js` website, and 2. iframe a  nginx+flutter web application. So, I thinking putting these 2 containers in a Fargate would be good. (Backend is API Gateway+Lambda+RDS, but that is another story)